# Zxing camera and preview frame format (YUV, RGB...)

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, zxing, yuv

I'm using the Zxing API to decode some QR Code images.
I need to convert the YUV format to -> RGB format to be used in an other application.

I know the camera buffer returns a byte[] under the NV21 format (YUV), but which one is it ?

- Do I get a **YUV420** format ? Or a **YUV422** format ?
- If so, how do I convert this format to an RGB888 format ? Do I need
  to convert the YUV to YUV888 before that ?

Thanks for your time,

**EDIT:**
One thing I do not undestand is the length of the byte[] from the YUV420 preview frame. For a 1280*720 resolution , I get 1,382,400.00 bytes. How is it calculated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NV21 is basically YUV420. You can convert directly:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28NV21.29_to_ARGB8888_conversion

Comment: Oh, so if I just want RGB format, I would have to remove the alpha pixel after the wikipedia conversion?

Comment: Yeah just ignore that entirely. The code there just puts a 4th `0xFF` byte on top, which is already implicitly there in RGB888.

Comment: OK, will try. But are you sure it's YUV420 ? I do understand why I get 1 382 400 bytes for a resolution of 1280*720. Do you know how it is calculated ?

Comment: That's 921600 pixels, so 921600 bytes for Y. U and V are each 2x2 subsampled, so each has only 1/4th as many bytes. So U and V are each 230400 bytes. All three together are 1382400.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those clarifications

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, it is worth pointing out that the ZXing library includes [PlanarYUVLuminanceSource](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.java), which encapsulates this transform and can limit peak memory usage if the decoder access the data row-by-row.